# Slow IIS Release Environment, Quick Dev Environment

Tags: asp.net, performance, linq-to-sql, user-controls, iis-7.5

I've been researching and researching and trying to optimize an application I've been building that uses asp.net C# user controls (it will move to MVC/Angular/Razor, eventually, but for now it has to stay as user controls).

On my local machine, I'm getting an average page generation time of about 150 - 500 ms. Which is excellent. Once it goes up to the server, load times balloon to 600 - 1200 ms. Once you factor in download speed, response times, latency, etc, etc, customers are looking at 1.5s - 2.2s DOM ready page. I'm aiming to have those times in the .7 - 1.2s DOM ready area.

Here's a breakdown of the page load times on the local host:

```
         Page PreInit:    0 |    0
             BindData:   58 |   58
  Content Page Loaded:    2 |   60
    Master Page Fixed:    0 |   60
        Binding Child:  150 |  210
  Bind Data Completed:    0 |  210
        Page Rendered:   74 |  284
```

And here's the exact same page loaded on the server:

```
         Page PreInit:    0 |    0
             BindData:  401 |  401
  Content Page Loaded:    8 |  409
    Master Page Fixed:    0 |  409
        Binding Child:  108 |  517
  Bind Data Completed:    0 |  517
        Page Rendered:  356 |  873
```

I get that my LINQ to SQL calls are slowing down the BindData() function and I am willing to accept the 340ms slow down as the server is running more than 15 websites. I don't plan on adding more.

The one that's bothering me, is the time from the end of the BindData() function to the Page_PreRenderComplete event. We have a 74ms load time, as compared to a 356ms load time on the production server. It's baffling to me that it takes 5 times longer to transform the page into HTML.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!!

*As a note, my local host is running through IIS as a website pointed to 127.0.0.1. Both servers (local and production) are running IIS 7.5. The release version of my application has debug="false" and both are set to run in ASP.net 4.6.1*

**FULL ASPX PAGE CODE**

Please excuse the stopwatch stuff. That's just so I can figure out where the slow down is occurring.

```
public partial class Page_Content : BasePage
{
    public string loadTime = "<pre>";
    public decimal elapsed = 0;
    public System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch timer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Start();
        loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Page PreInit", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
    }

    protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer.Stop();
        loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Page Rendered", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        lblTime.Text = loadTime + "</pre>";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            BindData();
    }

    protected void BindData()
    {
        loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "BindData", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        string imgURL = "";
        string mobileURL = "";
        var cp = contentService.GetContentPage(cpName, true, false);
        if (cp != null)
        {
            loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Content Page Loaded", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var _master = (CMS.Master)this.Master;
            if (_master != null)
                _master.SetPageClass(String.Format("content-page page-{0}", cp.Name));

            loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Master Page Fixed", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            ctrlContent.item = cp;
            ctrlContent.OverWriteSEO = true;
            ctrlContent.BindData();

            loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Binding Child", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

            if (settingService.GetSettingValueByNameBool("Media.ContentPiece.ShowHeaderImage", false))
            {
                if (cp.ImageID.HasValue)
                {
                    imgURL = pictureService.GetPictureUrl(cp.ImageID.Value, settingService.GetSettingValueByNameInt("Media.Carousel.ImageSize", 1000));
                    mobileURL = pictureService.GetPictureUrl(cp.ImageID.Value, settingService.GetSettingValueByNameInt("Media.Carousel.Mobile.ImageSize", 768));
                }

                loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Pictures Loaded", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imgURL))
                {
                    pnlMainImage.Visible = true;
                    pnlMainImage.Attributes.Add("style", String.Format("background-image: url('{0}')", imgURL));
                    pnlMainMobile.Visible = true;
                    pnlMainMobile.Attributes.Add("style", String.Format("background-image: url('{0}')", mobileURL));
                    pnlPageHeader.CssClass = "image-header-adjust inner-bound";
                }
            }

            loadTime += String.Format("{0, 25}: {1, 4} | {2, 4}<br />", "Bind Data Completed", timer.ElapsedMilliseconds - elapsed, timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            elapsed = timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
        else
            Response.Redirect("~/");
    }

    public string cpName
    {
        get
        {
            return globalService.QueryString("ID");
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

After making some revisions upon inspection, thanks to @sh1rts, I found that there were a number of round trips to the database that were happening unnecessarily. I have minimized those, and have gained SIGNIFICANT improvements. However, it seems to be that the leach is clearly the amount of time it takes the application to transform the LINQ to SQL and return the collection from the Database. Which I'm assuming means that my production DB is returning values slower than my dev DB. Any help on optimizing that connection would be appreciated.

Here's the new times (average .8s - 1.2s to DOM-Ready)

```
         Page PreInit:    0 |    0
      Bind Data Fired:  298 |  298
  Content Page Loaded:    7 |  305
 Binding User Control:   11 |  316
  Bind Data Completed:    0 |  316
        Page Rendered:  151 |  467
```

Comment: Also, if anyone has some pointers on how I can make the SQL 2012 SP2 environments running on my local and dev server respond quicker, that would be great. Almost all of my data retrievals use LINQ to SQL.

Comment: Can you post *all* of the code that executes in between the end of BindData() and before Page_PreRenderComplete() please ?

Comment: I've posted the full code for the page in an edit. I'm stepping through now to see what other code is hit elsewhere after the BindData completes, because there is no more code on the aspx page, but there are several user controls left to render.

I think the fact may be that it's time to get rid of AjaxControlToolkit completely and build AJAX replacements for those things.

Comment: Turns out there's a couple more SQL calls being handled afterwards. I'm going to clean those up and see where that gets me. 

I will post an update once I've cleaned those up. it looks like my issue here is speeding up the SQLs in the production environment as compared to the localhost environment.

Comment: @sh1rts, I can't thank you enough. Your SIMPLE question pointed me in the right direction. It turns out that there were about 6 more calls to the database after the page finished binding. I've now made that into one call, and then passed that collection to the user controls from their parent control. With a little bit of linq to entities, I'm able to produce the same result without having to make all of those round trips to the database. The question now becomes, how do I speed up the SQL responses on the server. I will edit my question tomorrow to reflect that.